# Compiler thinks new array is creating new object?

Tags: c++

So, I'm currently trying to write a program with two different constructors, one default and one with input. These constructors are intended to initialize a global array to either the default length or the length specified by parameter.

Currently I have declared:

```
    Room *rooms;
```

in the header file as a private variable.
Then I have in the constructor:

```
    rooms = new Room[defaultRoomCapacity];
```

On compile, I get an error saying no matching function call to the constructor of the Room class. It seems as though it thinks I'm trying to make rooms an instance of Room? I am aware there are other methods of implementing this, but I am just curious what the issue could be.

Thanks

Comment: When you dynamically allocate memory for a number of objects, i.e. creating a "dynamic array", then each object in that array will be *constructed* which of course involves calling the constructor.

Comment: Also, in the future whenever you think "dynamic array" you should next be thinking about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). The [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) is there to make your life easier, and it really *do* make your life so much easier as a C++ programmer.

Comment: ah I think I understand. So it doesn't simply create null values at all the indices of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it calls default ctor. Make sure you declared and defined it along with a special ctor.

Comment: Thank you! Completely forgot to create a default constructor.